# Tool to parse log files generated from Enterprise Library Logging Application Block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, logfiles

I have a bunch of log files generated out of the Enterprise Library Logging Application Block. These files contains all categories of logs. Is there any tool or any way to parse these files and show in a tabular form or support querying?

Comment: This may not solve your immediate problem, but in the future, you could separate it out write to different logs based on different categories.  No parsing necessary if you do that.

Comment: @Mark In my case, I do have segregated based on category and still need to parser to organize and display information to scrutinize. i.e. DEBUG level logging is enabled based on need which log enormous information and I need to scrutinize those information to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft's LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) should do the trick.

However, the Enterprise Library Logging application block provides considerable flexibility. Are the logs in question disk files? Are you using the default "Text Formatter"? The version of the Enterprise Library might be relevant (haven't used it since v2.1).

Myself, I just used GNU UnxUtils grep (and etc.) to get what I needed.

PS
[Jeff Atwood's Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html) has a good LogParser write-up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at using [LogParser](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LogParser41) from the [EntLibContrib project](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com).  It uses the Enterprise Library template to parse the file.